# How do I remove a package while there are unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, dependencies

This might be a case of the XY problem, so I'll try to explain the situation.

It have `unity-greeter-badges` installed, and I just enabled the Elementary OS ppa (`elementary-os/stable`), and attempted to install `pantheon`. One of `pantheon`'s dependencies is `pantheon-xsession-settings`.

The problem is that `pantheon-xsession-settings` and `unity-greeter-badges` both try to provide `/usr/share/unity-greeter/custom_pantheon_badge.png`. Because of this, it gives an error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pantheon-xsession-settings_0.5-0~77~ubuntu0.4.1_all.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/unity-greeter/custom_pantheon_badge.png', which is also in package unity-greeter-badges 0.4-0ubuntu3
```

The only way I see to resolve it would be to uninstall `unity-greeter-badges`, which I can't do because of `apt` checks for and sees `pantheon`'s unmet dependencies, and won't let me uninstall or install anything until they're resolved, and I can't resolve them until it's uninstalled...

What do I do?

Before you suggest it, `sudo apt install -f` shows the same error.

Comment: **To the trigger-happy OT close voters:** This question is *not* about Elementary OS. It's about Ubuntu with the Elementary OS *PPA* enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
dpkg --force-overwrite -i
```

works. The `.deb` file should be in `/var/lib/apt/cache` or a similar directory (downloaded by `apt-get install`). Otherwise you can download it into the current working directory with:

```
apt-get download pantheon-xsession-settings
```

Comment: I made the `--force` option more specific (`--force-overwrite`) to not force other things by accident that are more destructive than overwriting an icon file. +1